# Strange ng-class behaviour

Tags: angularjs

I'm playing around with angular and have encountered a strange behaviour of `ng-class` directive. Here is my app template:

```
<body ng-app>
  {{ isSidebarExpanded }}
  <div ui-view="sidebar" ng-class="{true:'expanded', false:'collapsed'}[isSidebarExpanded]"></div>
</body>
```

And now - when i'm changing `isSidebarExpanded` in my controller, the first line show it's content (which is true / false) without any issue but using it in `ng-class` produces:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

I can say it's `ng-class` fault cause when i remove the  part, it throws that error. I'm not sure which part of my code would be helpfull here cause it seems really confusing to me.

Comment: Works for me. Which version of angular do you use?

Comment: I'm using 1.2.16. the `isSidebarExpanded` variable is handled in a bit more complex way than regular. It's passwd from the rootScope. But, anyway, the first line works great so the question is - what can be possibly going wrong in here? What are the options ?

Comment: If it works for me, but not for you, then the problem is in the code you didn't show. Usually you would write `ng-class={expanded: isSidebarExpanded ...`, btw.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and temporarily solved it by creating a simple alternative directive `ng-class-alt`, which does the same job for this case. Note that `app` is my angular module.

```
app.directive('ngClassAlt', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      ngClassAlt: '=ngClassAlt'
    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('ngClassAlt', function (newVal) {
        _.each(scope.ngClassAlt, function(val, key) {
          if(val)
            elm.addClass(key);
          else
            elm.removeClass(key);
        });
      }, true);
    }
  };
});
```

Ugly AngularJS bugs inspire me to find ugly solutions... Hope this helps you.

Comment: my AngularJS version is also 1.2.16 by the way